# Why are we more sensitive to green light when 65% of our cone cells are red cone cells?

Tags: eyes, human-eye

I read, "human eyes are most sensitive in 555nm which is green. Human eyes are more sensitive to green than to red, and in low-light conditions even more to cyan than to green."

But it doesn't explain: Why are we more sensitive to green light when 65% of our cone cells are red cone cells?